# Issues with Mirah generating stubs out of seemingly random packages

Tags: codenameone

When building my cn1 project I hit the following exception

```
redacted-path\nbproject\mirah-build-cn1.xml:152: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find stub for interface ItemPrice>
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitClassImpl(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:764)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitClass(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:695)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:720)
    at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:68)
    at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:91)
    at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:99)
    at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitCompilationUnit(TreeScanner.java:120)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitCompilationUnit(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:278)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:550)
    at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:68)
    at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:91)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compile(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:887)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileFile(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:176)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:213)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:216)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:216)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:216)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:216)
    at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:195)
    at ca.weblite.asm.WLMirahCompiler.compile(WLMirahCompiler.java:208)
    at ca.weblite.mirah.ant.MirahcTask.execute(MirahcTask.java:158)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor276.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:350)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:449)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:470)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1361)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:261)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:574)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:128)
```

The build complains about not finding stub for interface `ItemPrice` but this interface is not referenced from within the package or class I am generating a `data_mapper` for. 
I further investigated the `build/mirah_tmp` folder. Indeed Mirah tried generating stubs for non-referenced interface in a different package.

**To demonstrate this problem**, I created the following [simplified project (accessible on github)](https://github.com/3lix/MirahTest) out of a basic `Hello World` cn1 template.

In this simplified project structure, I have the following three packages:

```
1. com.company.project
    MyApplication.java
2. com.company.project.firstmodel
    AuthContext.java
    DataMappers.mirah
3. com.company.project.secondmodel
    Address.java
```

The `DataMappers.mirah` only references `AuthContext` along with its package. And [AuthContext](https://github.com/3lix/MirahTest/blob/master/src/com/company/project/firstmodel/AuthContext.java) does not reference in any way [Address](https://github.com/3lix/MirahTest/blob/master/src/com/company/project/secondmodel/Address.java).

```
package com.company.project.firstmodel

data_mapper AuthContext:AuthContextMapper
```

On build, looking at `build/mirah-tmp` , it seems that stubs were also unexpectedly generated for `Address.java` [as evident by the uploaded github build folder](https://github.com/3lix/MirahTest/tree/master/build/mirah_tmp/java_stub_dir/com/company/project).

I am under the impression that mirah attempts to generate stubs for literally every file within my project (yet to verify since it's already failing due to `not finding stub for interface`)

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Screenshot seen on netbeans startup after moving my app source files to a new project.
[image]

Comment: I asked Steve to answer as I'm not familiar enough with Mirah but is it possible you have a wayward `>` character in one of your files?

Answer (score 0):

The Mirah integration works by first compiling stubs for all of the java classes in the project.  It then compiles the mirah files, using the compiled java stubs for dependencies.  It then does a final pass, compiling all of the java files completely.   The first step, compiling the stubs, needs to compile all files in the project because it doesn't yet know which files the mirah files reference - since that happens in step 2.

If you can put together a test case that reproduces your error, I can try to troubleshoot the error further.

Comment: thanks, I tested with interface reference in ```Address.java``` and that seems to work. Per what you explained above this makes sense due to the pre compilation step of all java classes.
But my project is still failing, I tried starting a new project and moving source files there. The project would not build due to the stacktrace I shared in initial question post.  But I notice now , on netbeans startup,  the project gets highlighted in red and there's this complain message "build-mirah file/folder could not be found in project(projectName)" . I will update the initial post with a screenshot

Comment: Those directories will be created when mirah does a successful build.   Ie solve your first problem, and the second problem will solve itself.

Comment: I spent a little more time. I was able to reproduce with the following project https://github.com/3lix/MirahTest6 . If you pull this repo and build, the build initially may be successful ( at least it is on my machine). But then If you add a newline to DataMappers.mirah + save. Then remove that added newline if you wish  + resave (i.e modify .mirah file in any way) Then the project no longer builds for me. I am hoping you would be able to reproduce.

Comment: Steve, please let me know if you had a chance to run the test case provided above, based on MirahTest6 repo